# Design Pattern: torch.hub.load() design pattern? How to make model loader?

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns, pytorch, torch

The `torch.hub.load()` method defined [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/hub.py), What is the design pattern of this method and how to replicate the functionality of loading multiple models using a command similar to

```
model = createModel('model_name')
```

Thanks